# Compatibility condition of symplectic form and complex structure

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manfiold.

The cotangent bundle $T^*M$ of a manifold $M$ admits a canonical symplectic form. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_one-form).

Let $g$ be the canonical induced metric on $T^*M$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086836/canonical-riemannian-metric-on-the-cotangent-bundle?noredirect=1#comment4288689_2086836)

Every symplectic manifold with a given riemannian metric admits an almost complex structure in a canonical way. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084282/canonical-almost-complex-structure-on-symplectic-manifold?noredirect=1#comment4284609_2084282).

Can we say anything about this almost complex structure? For example, does it take on a nice form because we are using a symplectic structure and metric which  in a sense keep track of the fact that $T^*M$ is locally a product?

(Sorry this is a little vague. I'm note exactly sure what to expect, but I hope what I am saying makes a little bit of sense.)

Comment: I think there is a large set of compatible almost complex structures, but the set of compatible almost complex structures is contractible in any suitable topology. The advantage is the positivity of $\omega(\ ,J\ )$. This causes the Cauchy Riemann equations for mapped in surfaces (curves) to be elliptic, so analyzing the properties of their dilution sets is generically very tractable.